# how to change the scalaPB default path of protobuf files?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I have a build.sbt for a couple of packages in the same project.
When I do sbt compile, my protobuf files are under [packagename]/src/main/protobuf/*,
so it won't scan these files since they have that additional package name in the path.
How to change the default protobuf file path?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether your sbt build is a single or multi-project build. You can tell that it is a multi-project build if you see lines like `val someSubProject = project.in(file(...)`.

If your `build.sbt` is a single project build, you can add a line to customize where protos are being scanned:

```
Compile / PB.protoSources += file("pkgname/src/main/protobuf")
```

If you have a multi-project build with a project `proj1`, then it should already work in the way you expect:

```
val proj1 = project.in(file("proj1"))
    .settings(
        PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
          scalapb.gen(javaConversions=true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scalapb"
        ),

        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
        )
    )
```

then sbt-protoc will generate sources for the protos under `proj1/src/main/protobuf`. The sources will get compiled as poart of the `proj1` project.

You can customize the path it looks for by setting `Compile / PB.protoSources` within that project's setting. For example, if you want it to generate source for protos that are in another top-level directory, you can do:

```
val proj1 = project.in(file("proj1"))
    .settings(
        PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
          scalapb.gen(javaConversions=true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scalapb"
        ),

        Compile / PB.protoSources :=
          Seq((ThisBuild / baseDirectory).value / "somewhere" / "protos"),

        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
        )
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `AkkaGrpcPlugin` and a multi-project SBT configuration.

Put the `.proto` files in a separate project and make the others depend on it. This project just has a single directory `<root>/grpc/src/main/protobuf` containing the `.proto` files. When this project is compiled it will create all the stub files which can be picked up by other projects that depend on it.

Here is an outline `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val top_level =
  (project in file("."))
    .aggregate(grpc, main)

lazy val grpc =
  project
    .in(file("grpc"))
    .settings(
      ???
    )
    .enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)

lazy val main =
  project
    .in(file("main"))
    .settings(
      ???
    )
    .dependsOn(grpc)
```

And add this to `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "1.1.1")
```

Comment: Downvoted since the OP did not indicate they are using Akka or GRPC at all, and the provided answer adds Akka as a library dependencies to the project. The question as stated can be answered by passing a documented configuration setting to sbt-protoc.